# Problema al crear documento XML desde una clase

Tags: c#, xml

Desarrollo una aplicación donde creo un documento XML desde una clase la cual serializo, el problema se presenta cuando cierto nodo debe repetirse más de una vez, me explico el documento que estoy creando es una factura si vendo un artículo el nodo aparece una vez, si vendo dos artículos el nodo aparecerá dos veces y así sucesivamente.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear este nodo  tantas veces como número de productos tenga mi factura?

El código que utilizo para agregar el nodo es el siguiente, ¿cómo lo puedo modificar  para que se repita tantas veces como sea necesario?

```
 DetalleServicio = new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle[]
                  {
                      new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle
                   {
                      NumeroLinea = numeroLinea,
                      Codigo = new CodigoType[]
                      {
                          new CodigoType
                          {
                            Tipo=(CodigoTypeTipo)Enum.Parse(typeof(CodigoTypeTipo), tipo),
                            Codigo= codigo
                          }
                      },
                      Cantidad = cantidad,
                      UnidadMedida=(UnidadMedidaType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UnidadMedidaType), unidadMedida),
                      UnidadMedidaComercial=unidadComercial,
                      Detalle= detalle,
                      PrecioUnitario=precio,
                      MontoTotal=precio * cantidad,
                      MontoDescuento=montoDescuento,
                      NaturalezaDescuento= naturalezaDescuento,
                      SubTotal= subTotal,
                      MontoTotalLinea= precio * cantidad - montoDescuento
                  }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Construi este metodo que devuelve una lista , segun lo que vi aqui :[Problema al crear documento XML desde una clase](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/f993c2b0-e30f-4bbc-87e0-30f4647bb388/como-repetir-nodo-en-documento-xml-desd-clase-serializada-?forum=vcses)

```
  public List<FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle> DetalleFactura(List<TributarioCr.ClaseUtil.LineaDetalle> detalleFactura)
        {
            List<FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle> detalleServicio = new List<FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= detalleFactura.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle linea = new FacturaElectronicaLineaDetalle
                {
                    NumeroLinea = (i + 1).ToString (),
                    Codigo = new CodigoType[]
                      {
                          new CodigoType
                          {
                            Tipo=(CodigoTypeTipo)Enum.Parse(typeof(CodigoTypeTipo), detalleFactura[i].tipo),
                            Codigo=detalleFactura[i].codigo
                          }
                      },
                    Cantidad = Convert.ToDecimal(detalleFactura[i].cantidad),
                    UnidadMedida = (UnidadMedidaType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UnidadMedidaType), detalleFactura[i].unidadMedida),
                    UnidadMedidaComercial = detalleFactura[i].unidadMedidaComercial,
                    Detalle = detalleFactura[i].detalleServicio,
                    PrecioUnitario = Convert.ToDecimal(detalleFactura[i].precioUnitario),
                    MontoTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(detalleFactura[i].montoTotal),
                    MontoDescuento = Convert.ToDecimal(detalleFactura[i].montoDescuento),
                    // MontoDescuentoSpecified=true,
                    NaturalezaDescuento = detalleFactura[i].naturalezaDescuento,
                    SubTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(detalleFactura[i].subTotal),

                    MontoTotalLinea = Convert.ToDecimal(detalleFactura[i].montoTotalLinea)
                };

                detalleServicio.Add(linea);
            }

            return detalleServicio;
        }
```